# Can fbterm support 256 colors?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, colors, tty, bashrc

I have Arch without X and want to make my console solarized. I think I can't do that in tty, so I had installed fbterm and tried to play with fbtermrc, bashrc etc.

$ tput colors

256

$ xterm-color-count.sh -v

0

https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count

Comment: you have to force TERM="fbterm" when the console starts. Also as Thomas Dickey points out, FBTerm uses "private escape sequences" which turns out to be _decimal_ values, _NOT_ hexi-decimal values like XTerm does, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316878/solarized-colorscheme-in-fbterm/388587#388587

Answer (score 3):

According to its [webpage](http://code.google.com/p/fbterm/): **2009-03-14 Release version 1.4** "added private escape sequences for 256 color mode support".

However,

- it goes on to say that those sequences are not compatible with any other terminal,
- the developers made a custom terminal description for this named "fbterm",
- that terminal description is not installed on your system unless you happened to do this, because
- it is not part of ncurses (see [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html)).